# Select a sum of totals as well as a different sum with date clause without sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problems when building a query to get the values of two sum totals of a time taken field in the same table.

Ideally I am looking to select total of values within a date range but also get the total before the date range is applied in the MySQL clause.

I have built the below using a sub query but this is slow and clocks in at 8.5 seconds!

Is there anyway to speed this up?

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.forename,
       u.surname,
       c.client_name,
       p.project_name,
       SUM(t.time_taken) AS total_project_time_between_dates,
       (SELECT SUM(st.time_taken) 
        FROM tbl_mt_tasks st 
        WHERE st.user_id = u.user_id 
          AND st.project_id = p.project_id 
        GROUP BY st.user_id, st.project_id, st.client_id  
        LIMIT 1) as total_project_time
FROM tbl_mt_tasks t 
  JOIN tbl_mt_clients c ON t.client_id = c.client_id 
  JOIN tbl_mt_projects p ON t.project_id = p.project_id 
  JOIN tbl_mt_users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE t.date_created  BETWEEN '2015-04-16' AND '2015-04-22' 
  AND u.status != 100 
GROUP BY t.project_id, t.client_id, t.user_id 
ORDER BY  project_name ASC
```

Comment: have you researched the WITH ROLLUP modifier? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Just a few comment: 1) you can remove LIMIT 1 from the sub-select, select sum never returns more than 1 row. 2) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Thank you @jarlh. I have taken this out!

Comment: @NeilYoung, sorry, I was wrong. Forgot the GROUP BY... Put LIMIT back...

Answer (score 0):

Last answer seems to have been deleted but was in fact correct! To filter out the results I just needed to use the HAVING clause!

```
    SELECT 
        u.user_id,
        u.forename,
        u.surname,
        c.client_name,
        p.project_name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.date_created  BETWEEN '2015-04-16' AND '2015-04-22' THEN t.time_taken ELSE 0 END) AS total_project_time_between_dates,
        SUM(time_taken) as total_project_time
    FROM tbl_mt_tasks t 
      JOIN tbl_mt_clients c ON t.client_id = c.client_id 
      JOIN tbl_mt_projects p ON t.project_id = p.project_id 
      JOIN tbl_mt_users u ON t.user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE u.status != 100 
    GROUP BY 
        u.user_id,
        c.client_id,
        p.project_id 
    HAVING total_project_time_between_dates > 0
    ORDER BY  project_name ASC
```